# Is there an svn command to find out the last revision to change a particular file or a directory?

Tags: svn, commit

Is there an svn command to find out the last revision to change a particular file or a directory?

Comment: It indicates that you have answers or comments on any of the stackexchange sites.  They show in the "inbox" when you click on the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
svn log -l n <file/directory>
```

where n is the latest n revisions. So if you want to check the last revision it will be n will be 1:

```
svn log -l 1 <file>
```

With some judicious use of grep the information returned can be reduced.

Gleaned from the Lazarus mailing list

Answer (score 3):

See the **[Browsing](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.tour.history.browsing)** section of the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html) (in it 1.6 edition):

The command **[`svn list`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.list)** should allow you to get the laster revision:

> If you want a more detailed listing, pass the `--verbose (-v)` flag to get output like this:

```
$ svn list -v http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn
  20620 harry            1084 Jul 13  2006 README
  23339 harry                 Feb 04 01:40 branches/
  21282 sally                 Aug 27 09:41 developer-resources/
  23198 harry                 Jan 23 17:17 tags/
  23351 sally                 Feb 05 13:26 trunk/
```

Comment: I took the liberty to complete your answer. I don't like answers which are just a link. I prefer copying extracts from that link in order to get the relevant information without having to leave SO. Feel free to revert if your disagree.

Comment: I have edited the question to change 'commit' to 'revision' as answer is not what I expected

Comment: No, your revisions are very good.  I don't always have time to do all that I'd like; I also don't think it's a bad thing to ask the OP to do some further investigation on their own.  If they couldn't find the link that I posted, perhaps it'll be their first exposure to a fine reference like the Red Bean book.

Comment: +1 but it is a bit dangerous to link to the nightly build of the svn book, as sections may eventually disappear or be moved for major SVN releases. Better to link to the latest released edition of the book (currently for svn 1.5) when possible.

Comment: as forecasted...the links in this answer are now broken.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that `svn info [<filename>]` shows is `Last Changed Rev`, that may differ from `Revision` - working copy's revision.